# Controller action not working with external callback

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment, controllers, action

I have a custom payment module where I need a controller for callback to get notified about the payment, but the payment service only gives me the error that the response contains html. Also, in the controller action I log every request and there aren't any requests from the callback service coming in. When I cann the exact same URL manually in the browser, everything works as expected and the callback also works fine with a simple test php file, only with Magento controllers it doesn't. I just don't understand why I don't get the request. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is it hosted on a local server or hosted on a server where the site is reachable?

http://localhost or any local network address is just unreachable from  outside.

Comment: Yes it's on a hosted server of cource, the site is absolutely reachable from outside.

Comment: Enable apache log first and see if you receiving the requests. If it is receiving the requests, then its a Magento problem and we will look into the Magento code.

Comment: run something like this: tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log